# How to customize a textbox using the jquery mobile css classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, jquery-mobile

I know that Jquery Mobile appends additional classes to elements but I was wondering if the order of classes will always be the same.

What I mean by this is if I have a textbox input say with a custom class

eg.

```
<input type="text" class="myTextboxClass" />
```

Jquery mobile will add other class to the element such as so that it'll be:

```
<input type="text" class="myTextboxClass ui-input-text ui-body-b" />
```

If I want to retrieve just my class and nothing else; would I be able to just split the class string and retrieve only the first one so that I get only `myTextboxClass`?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I need to do this while keeping all the jquery mobile styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving data-role="none".it prevents the css given by jquery mobile css file classes.

```
<input type="text" class="myTextboxClass" data-role="none" />
```

Now you can customize the design of your textbox accordingly.
You are always allowed to edit the css classes in jquery mobile css file then add the classes you want to customize them. 
And also use uncompressed(not minified) version of css for debugging.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this. But is there any way to keep the jquery styling and still do what I needed to?

Comment: You are always allowed to edit the css classes in jquery mobile css file then add the classes you want to customize them.

Comment: And also I forgot to mention not to download minified version of css.Instead use uncompressed version for debugging.